# Typescript module augmentation with ambient declaration

Tags: typescript-typings

Just a question on whether this problem with typings is possible to fix with an ambient type/module declaration and how.  In actuality I'll see about getting the typings fixed in the library in question, but sometimes that's not possible.

I'm trying [@finos/perspective](https://github.com/finos/perspective).  There is a `worker` object that has a factory method for creating a table:  `worker.table`.

**@finos/perspective/index.d.ts**

```js
export type PerspectiveWorker = {
    table(data: TableData, options?: TableOptions): Table;
};
```

The `data` parameter is of type TableData.

**@finos/perspective/index.d.ts**

```js
export type TableData = string | Array<object> | {[key: string]: Array<object>} | {[key: string]: string};
```

The problem is that `worker.table()` also actually takes an `ArrayBuffer` to allow creation of a table from an [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) binary buffer.  So, `TableData` should have `| ArrayBuffer` added to it's type signature, but since it does not have this typescript is complaining:

```js
Argument of type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | object[] | { [key: string]: object[]; } | { [key: string]: string; } | Schema'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'Schema'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'ArrayBuffer'.ts(2345)
```

If I manually edit **@finos/perspective/index.d.ts** and add `| ArrayBuffer` as in:

```js
    export type TableData = string | Array<object> | {[key: string]: Array<object>} | {[key: string]: string} | ArrayBuffer;
```

Then typescript stops complaining (and the code actually works regardless of whether typescript complains or not).

Is there a way to fix this with an ambient declaration?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext", "ESNext.AsyncIterable"],
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,
        "types": ["node"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/_declarations"]
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**src/_declarations/perspective.d.ts**

```js
import type { TableData } from "@finos/perspective";

declare module "@finos/perspective" {
    export type TableData =
        | string
        | Array<Record<string, unknown>>
        | { [key: string]: Array<Record<string, unknown>> }
        | { [key: string]: string }
        | ArrayBuffer;
}
```

I also tried:

```js
export type TableData = TableData | ArrayBuffer;
```

All of this is failing to stop typescript from complaining.  I sometimes struggle with things like this, trying to augment a third-party module via ambient type declarations and wonder if anyone could shed some light on how this might be solvable without changing the third-party library.